# Pass kwargs to dynamically instantiated Python Class

Tags: python, class, eval

There maybe (usually is) a better way to do what I'm trying, but I am currently making a list of objects like this:

```
my_list = [MyObject(d**) for d in db.myobjects.find({...})]
```

This works great because it creates converts the dictionary objects returned by my database query into "MyObjects", adding in a bunch of class methods and properties.

How can I do the same thing when the Class name is dynamically inserted at runtime?  I can create the classes dynamically using `eval()` but how can I insert the dictionary objects?

```
my_list = [eval('FooObject') for d in db.fooobjects.find({...})]  # needs kwargs from dicts
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider using `globals()` instead of `eval()`, especially if the class string is from user input.

To your actual question, it works exactly the same way - `eval('FooClass')` or `globals()['FooClass']` gives you the *class itself*, it doesn't instantiate it. That means you can instantiate it by calling it, same as if you know its name ahead of time:

```
globals()['FooClass'](**d)
```

Comment: Sounds great, thank you.  However `globals('FooClass')` is giving me a TypeError.. too many args..??